# FFmpeg - Check if all video files have concatenated correctly into one video

Tags: ios, swift, video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I am concatenating thousands of .ts files into an mp4 which works great but is there a way to know which files have already been concatenated with FFmpeg?

The issue I have is I am concatenating multiple videos back to back and if the app is closed off during the concatenation process. The concatenating of the videos may not be complete. I can check if the files exist but the size of the files could be wrong if not all the clips have been concatenated. Is there a way to know if all the files have been concatenated properly?

My current idea is if the app is closed before it has completed concatenating, I would delete the mp4 file and restart concatenating the video again but this time consuming especially if the files concatenated properly the first time.

Any ideas would be great thanks

**ffmpegCommand**

```
 ffmpeg -f concat -i \(videoFile) -c:v copy -c:a copy \(outputFile)
```

I am using the cocoa pod **mobile-FFmpeg**
https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg

Link to **FFmpeg Concatenate function**
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Comment: Compare the total duration of the inputs to the duration of the output. See [How to get video duration in seconds?](https://superuser.com/a/945604/). Or check exit status from ffmpeg.

Comment: @llogan thanks, I ended up adding a completion handler and created plist to store which ones were completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way to get around this was to create a completion handler when the file finished concatenating and have a plist file for example which would keep track of the videos that were concatenated properly or not.

I load the plist file to check if the videos are concatenated properly and if they aren't concatenated properly, I remove the ones that aren't and I concatenate them again.